# Prove that if $(X,\theta)$ is a $T_{3} $ space and A is a dense subset of $X$, $\chi(a,A)=\chi(a,X),\forall a\in A$

Tags: general-topology

Prove that if $(X,\theta)$ is a $T_{3} $ space and A is a dense subset of $X$, $\chi(a,A)=\chi(a,X),\forall a\in A$, where

$\chi(x,X)=min\{|B(x)|\big|B(x)\text{ is a local base at  }x\} $

So, because to every local base $B(x)$ at x in X corresponds a local base at x in A, namely $B^{A}(x)=\{U\cap A\big|U\in B(x)\},$ and every open in A subset is in the form $U\cap A \text{ for some }U\in\theta$, we get that $\chi(a,A)\leq\chi(a,X)$ since it is possible that $U_1\cap A=U_2\cap A$ for $U_1\neq U_2$. Is that correct so far? If so, how do I prove that the latter impossible?

Comment: $\text{RO}(A) = \{U \cap A: U \in \text{RO}(X)\}$, and regular open sets form a base (and local base at each point) for a $T_3$ space.

Comment: I can use that $\overline{U\cap A}= \overline{U}$ for A-dense, and thus $\overline{U_{1}}=\overline{U_{2}}$ and if I use that $U_1,U_2$ are regular open, I get that $U_{1}=U_{2}$, but how am I sure that the RO base is the one with the minimal cardinality?

Comment: For every local base of a certain size there is one of equal size consisting of regular open sets.

Comment: In your definition of $\chi,$ how can a set, namely A be a local base?  For example, how is Q a local base for 0?

Comment: a typo, it was meant to be "B(x) is a local base", with Henno's advise I figured it out